# How to replace a specific character in a text file by giving the index value?

Tags: java, file-io

Came across this code which replaces all the characters of the given value.

```
File temp = File.createTempFile("newfile", ".txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(temp);
    Reader reader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

    while (br.ready()) {
        fw.write(br.readLine().replaceAll("n", "j") + "\n");
    }

    fw.close();
    br.close();
    reader.close();

    temp.renameTo(file);
}
```

instead of replacing all 'n's with 'j's isn't there a way to specify the index I want to change only?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. That one line inside of the `while` statement does many things, and can be expanded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`replaceFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) (that accepts a regex), using the following pattern:

```
(?<=.{N-1}).
```

Where "N" is the index you want to replace.

Of course there are many alternatives, look at the [`String API`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to fuel your creative fire.

Comment: how can i do it using regex can you add some code please!!

Comment: how can i give the value to N?

Answer (score 0):

The line within the while statement as follows:

```
fw.write(br.readLine().replaceAll("n", "j") + "\n");
```

This can be expanded to:

```
String str = br.readLine();                   //get text
String replace = str.replaceAll("n", "j");    //replace content
replace = replace + "\n";                     //add new line
fw.write(replace);                            //write to file
```

For your instance of replacing a certain index, you would want to do something similar:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(br.readLine()); //Read line into StringBuilder
if(str.length() > 3)                //Check if string is long enough
    str.setChar(4, 'x');            //Replace character in line at index 4 to 'x'
fw.write(str);                      //write to file
```